# is it possible to merge 2 videos to a single video using FFMPEG in flutter

Tags: flutter, video, ffmpeg, merge

I am developing an application in flutter, user add two videos and I want to merge them into a single video and give the output containing two video side by side, the given videos will have different height and different width.

Currently am using a FFmpeg command
'-i $filePath -i ${widget.videopath} -filter_complex hstack $combinedvideopath'
to merge two video files.
it prompting me a error,

input 1 height 512 does not match input 0 height 1280.

Comment: You can first check whether FFMPEG does that or not, it's not specific to flutter.

Comment: thank you for answering, It's working fine with my terminal on Mac, i am searching for the exact command to merge two videos with different heights. it's working fine even in flutter if videos dimensions are same

Comment: Could you please post your answer if you found the solution. I am stuck on the same problem.